# Stop running javascript based on load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I am replacing a `div`'s content with externally loaded php using the Jquery `.load()` function, my problem is that I would like to write my javascript code for php files and save it in the bottom of the file.

So basically when I run the `.load()` function, the internal javascript of the file i'm loading, runs too. This works great so far. My problem is that when I run the `.load()` function again to load different content with different javascript into my `div`, the javascript of the previous file loaded, continues to run.

I need it to stop running the javascript of the last loaded php file, and load the new javascript.

For example, I have 1 div and 5 files, whenever I click a button, using the `load()` function, i inject the php and javascript of the page I have selected into the div. If each of my pages has this code at the bottom

```
 setInterval(function(){
   console.log("hello");
 },1000)
```

and I load each page 1 at a time, it stores the javascript and in result, runs console logs "hello" 5 times a second.

What I want it to do is remove the previous javascript, and load the new one everytime I select a new page.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: So you would need to store it in a varaible and clear it if it already exists

Comment: why use on load, you can use blur or a click event to fire it whenever you make that selection

Comment: store all of my external javascript in a variable and clear it before running the next? Apologies for seeming stupid, but how would i achieve this?

Comment: Sorry @Keith, i'm not using it on load, im running the `load()` function whenever I click a button

Comment: @Keith load as in http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 3):

You would need to store it into a variable and remove it if it exists.

```
if (window.myInterval) window.clearInterval(window.myInterval)
window.myInterval = setInterval(function(){
  console.log("hello");
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Could you possibly briefly explain how this works? Thanks :)

Comment: not sure what there is to explain.... clears the interval if it exists, setInterval returns an id, read the docs on MDN. http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setInterval.html

Answer (score 1):

Better you call the remove interval by using

```
clearInterval();
```

method, because once you call the

```
setInterval();
```

method, it will continue doing the function it is said to, until you leave the page or clear the interval.